# If else shorthand code for 3 situations

Tags: javascript

How would I go on about shortening the following piece of code?

```
if (typeof dIndex === 'undefined') {
    dPolylines = [];
} else {
    if (typeof rIndex === 'undefined') {
        dPolylines[dIndex] = [];
    } else {
        dPolylines[dIndex][rIndex] = [];
    }
}
```

I feel that these 8 lines of code can easily be converted to 3 lines maximum, but I have no proper idea on how to handle this.

I'm going to need this piece of code a couple of times throughout my code.

Comment: use `ternary` operator maybe?

Comment: I don't think you can make shorter version of that, because of different array keys

Comment: Code is broken. You use undefined `dIndex` in else branch

Comment: Code should ideally be readable and easy to understand.  Making it shorter for the sake of it is a bad habit.  You could cut out some of it, though, without making it less simple to understand.  Just use `if {} else if {} else {}`

Comment: @vp_arth: Updated code snippet.

Comment: @Archer: I'm going to need this specific type of if-else buildup a lot in my code, which is why I want it shortened.

Comment: I've added an answer showing a clearer version of my comment, along with an ever further trimmed version, that is still readable and simple to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there are a couple of solutions possible. The first one is to use the ternary operator, but it isn't all that clean:

```
typeof dIndex === 'undefined' ? dPolylines = [] : (typeof rIndex === 'undefined' ? dPolylines[dIndex] = [] : dPolylines[dIndex][rIndex] = []);
```

As you can see, it's just far too long. Considering Archer's answer, you'll have the following:

```
if (typeof dIndex === 'undefined') {
    dPolylines = [];
} else if (typeof rIndex === 'undefined') {
    dPolylines[dIndex] = [];
} else {
    dPolylines[dIndex][rIndex] = [];
}
```

This comes down to 6 lines, which is still pretty long. But since I'm going to need this piece of code multiple times throughout my original code, I converted it into a function:

```
dPolylines = clearDirectionsArray(dPolylines, dIndex, rIndex);

function clearDirectionsArray(array, dIndex, rIndex) {
    if (typeof dIndex === 'undefined') {
        array = [];
    } else if (typeof rIndex === 'undefined') {
        array[dIndex] = [];
    } else {
        array[dIndex][rIndex] = [];
    }

    return array;
};
```

This would eventually lower the amount of lines drastically throughout the code. Although this was not originally put up in the question.

Answer (score 1):

[Archer's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37296347/if-else-shorthand-code-for-3-situations#comment62115906_37296347) applied to your code:

```
if (typeof dIndex === 'undefined') {
    dPolylines = [];
} else if (typeof rIndex === 'undefined') {
    dPolylines[dIndex] = [];
} else {
    dPolylines[dIndex][rIndex] = [];
}
```

Not much shorter, but still comprehensible (maybe even more so than the original code).

Answer (score 1):

To make it shorter without loosing any readability, I'd recommend just trimming it slightly to this...

```
if (typeof dIndex === 'undefined') {
    dPolylines = [];
}
else if (typeof rIndex === 'undefined') {
    dPolylines[dIndex] = [];
} else {
    dPolylines[dIndex][rIndex] = [];
}
```

You could take it one step further and remove the braces like this...

```
if (typeof dIndex === 'undefined') dPolylines = [];
else if (typeof rIndex === 'undefined') dPolylines[dIndex] = [];
else dPolylines[dIndex][rIndex] = [];
```

I personally don't like that as it can lead to mistakes much easier than when braces are used, but each to their own.  It's still readable and is now only 3 lines long.

For the best of both worlds, you could simply reformat the first suggestion I made and make me cringe if I ever see any of your code :p

```
if (typeof dIndex === 'undefined') { dPolylines = []; }
else if (typeof rIndex === 'undefined') { dPolylines[dIndex] = []; }
else { dPolylines[dIndex][rIndex] = []; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
typeof dIndex !== 'undefined' ? dPolylines = [] : ElseCheck()


function ElseCheck(){
    typeof rIndex !== 'undefined' ? dPolylines[dIndex][rIndex] = [] : dPolylines[dIndex] = []
}
```

Just trying ternary condition

Answer (score 0):

```
function straightFill(obj, keys) {
   obj = obj || {};
   var cur = obj;
   var key = keys.shift();
   while (typeof key != 'undefined') {
     cur[key] = {};
     cur = cur[key];
     key = keys.shift();
   }
   console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
   return obj;
}

var a = {};
straightFill(a, ['key1', 'key2']);              // {"key1":{"key2":{}}}
straightFill(null, [undefined, 'key2']);        // {}
straightFill(null, ['key1', undefined, 'key2']);// {"key1":{}}
```

---

Why I use objects instead arrays?
You should not use arrays with insequenced or nonnumeric keys:

```
>> a = []
<< []
>> a['key'] = 5
<< 5
>> a
<< []
>> a.key
<< 5
>> a[2] = 4
<< 4
>> a
<< [undefined × 2, 4]
>> a.length
<< 3
>> Object.keys(a)
<< ["2", "key"]
```

---

Ternary solution:

```
typeof dIndex == 'undefined' ? dPolylines = [] :
    typeof rIndex == 'undefined' ? dPolylines[dIndex] = [] :
        dPolylines[dIndex][rIndex] = [];
```